# Having Trouble Identifying TCP Congestion Control Provider option: Default

Tags: tcp, windows-10, tcpip, windows-command-prompt

I am running a Windows 10 (Version 1909) OS and when I am entering the following command in CMD ...

```
netsh interface tcp show global
```

[image]

...I am able to see add-on congestion control provider set to "Default"

I would like to know what do you mean by "Default"?
Is CUBIC algorithm default or CTCP algorithm default? And how can I verify which is currently running?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Run in Powershell

```
 Get-NetTCPSetting | Select SettingName, CongestionProvider
```

Congestion Provider can only be modified on windows server OS